# How to find the probability of 3 scenarios

Tags: statistics, probability

I have a bucket of tennis balls(2) and baseballs(22) for a total of 24 balls in the bin.

I want to know what the probability is for 3 scenarios.

Each time I am going to pull out a total of 12 balls at random.

I want to know the probability after pulling out all 12 balls whats the likelihood:

1.) I pull out both(2) tennis balls
2.) I pull out 0 tennis balls
3.) I only pull 1 tennis ball?

Obviously the probabilities for all 3 of these questions have to add up to 1 or 100%

thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a mathematics, not programming, question.

Comment: no I would appreciate you not ... it can be done with programming if you knew how doesnt sound like you do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) when you sample without replacement. So let's if we use [hypergeom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html) from `scipy` in python:

```
from scipy.stats import hypergeom
import seaborn as sns
# M is total pool, n is number of successes, N is the number of draws
[M, n, N] = [22, 2, 12]
rv = hypergeom(M, n, N)
#the range of values we are interested in
x = np.arange(0, n+1)
pmf_tballs = rv.pmf(x)
```

the probabilities for 0,1,2

```
pmf_tballs
array([0.19480519, 0.51948052, 0.28571429])

sns.barplot(x=x,y=pmf_tballs,color="b")
```

[image]

You can calculate by brute force:

```
import itertools
balls = [int(i) for i in '1'*2 + '0'*20]
draws = itertools.combinations(balls, 12)
counts_by_tballs = {0:0,1:0,2:0}
for i in draws:
    counts[sum(i)] +=1

You get a tally of 0, 1 and 2:

counts
{0: 251940, 1: 671840, 2: 369512}
```

And the probability is the same as above with hypergeometric:

```
[i/sum(counts.values()) for i in counts.values()]
[0.19480519480519481, 0.5194805194805194, 0.2857142857142857]
```